# Measuring execution time and CPU usage for a Maple function

Tags: memory, time, maple

I'm working on writing a larger procedure in Maple and I'm trying to figure out why it running slow. I was thinking that if I could test certain subfunctions in the procedure for their execution time I could determine a better way to code it to make it run faster.

Is there a good way to measure the execution time or cpu use for a Maple function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the resource usage for an entire procedure, run it wrapped in **CodeTools:-Usage**. To see a line-by-line analysis of resource usage, use **CodeTools:-Profiling:-Profile**.